# Android Thread getName gives current class name

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In Android I have a class:

```
class A extends Thread {

    A() {
        setName("AThread");

    }

class SM extends StateMachine {

    class A1 extends State {

        @Override
        enter() {
            Log.d (TAG, "" + Thread.currentThread().getName()); // this gives A

           }    
       }  
   }  
}

class B {

    B1 () {
        new Handler(super.getLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mA = new A();               
            mA.start(); // start thread             
            }
        }, 0);
    }   
}
```

Class B object is running from an Android service.
SM is a state machine class. A1 is a State class.
So `enter()` is executed when I create a SM and switch to the state A1. SM object is created inside the Thread, run from the Thread. And switching to state also happens inside the Thread and run from the Thread.
`getName` gives A class name instead of Thread name "AThread".
 Why ?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you calling `methodA1`? Also, `currentThread()` is a method not a field.

Comment: When is `method A1` executed? Is it executed by thread `A` in the first place?

Comment: Edidted now to answer above questions.

Comment: Please post the actual code. This is confusing..

Comment: Sorry, can't post proprietary code. If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: You haven't shown where you create `A1` and which thread is calling `enter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, your StateMachine is running in Handler's thread context. 
I bet, even if you remove extend from Thread from Class A, your code will work fine.
Defining A to extend Thread is not really working executing the StateMachine on a different thread, rather it is executing in Looper's context.

Following code prints AThread.

```
public class StateMachineEx {

class A extends Thread {

    A() {
        setName("AThread");

    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
           Log.d ("XXX", "" + Thread.currentThread().getName()); // this gives A
    }
}

StateMachineEx(Context context) {
        new Handler(context.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                A mA = new A();               
                mA.start(); // start thread             
            }
        }, 0);
    }
```

}

Comment: So what is the difference in the above code ? You are starting A and printing the Thread name in run class. You are also starting A Thread from run of Handler.

Comment: Even if you remove extending class "A" from Thread class ,it will work. Yes I should have removed "extending Thread class".

Comment: In your example code "enter" function is directly called from Handler's context and that's the reason why you get the output "A" instead of AThread.

Comment: Your last comment is correct. Thanks.